# How to skip a portion of code on condition based, in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, conditional-statements

From within JasperReport code I want to skip a portion of code (SAY if value is 0) don't print that group of detail, otherwise do.

my JasperReport portion is below and what I want to do is here

```
//If $F{someField} == 0 ? SKIP THIS PORTION : TRUE
//How can I place a condition above here?
<group name="Customer">
     <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></groupExpression>
     <groupHeader></groupHeader>
</group>
```

Comment: `From within JasperReport code I want to skip a portion of code` - it is impossible. But you can use `printWhenExpression`. You can read [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf) for details

Comment: Or you can use *Java* API (*JasperReports API*, for example)

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem.  I think what I am going to do (although it is messy) is to have two subreports, one with the groupExpression and one without, and then use the condition to attach the correct subreport